# How to generate simple JSON object from json schema?

Tags: json, rest, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

is there any website or chrome-extension that generates sample JSON object from JSON schema?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are: [json schema faker](http://json-schema-faker.js.org/)

More information you can find here: [json schema implementations](http://json-schema.org/implementations.html)